# Transformation of attributes with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is the second day that I use XSLT, so I'm a total newbie. And now I want to use my attributes in calculations.

The XML I want to edit looks like this:

```
<position x="106" y="47" zIndex="6" width="30" height="5"/>
<position x="106" y="56" zIndex="7" width="30" height="5"/>
<position x="106" y="66" zIndex="8" width="30" height="5"/>
<position x="106" y="75" zIndex="9" width="30" height="5"/>
```

My XSLT Code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@x[parent::position]">
        <xsl:attribute name="x">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum((@x, 1000))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, in this code sample, I wanted to increase the x attribute by 1000, but it was just set them to 1000.
EDIT: I want to be able to use at least all numeric calculations and conditions(which refer to the current x value) like: `==`; `!=`; `>=`; `=<`; ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum((., 1000))"/>
```

Where `.` represents the current match (the `x` attribute). Doing `@x` would look for an `x` attribute on the current `x` attribute, which would not exist.

Although, having said that, you could just do this in this case....

```
<xsl:value-of select=". + 1000"/>
```

Note you can also simplify the template match, like so

```
<xsl:template match="position/@x">
    <xsl:attribute name="x">
        <xsl:value-of select=". + 1000"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

And if you are indeed using XSLT 2.0, you can simplify it even more, to this:

```
<xsl:template match="position/@x">
    <xsl:attribute name="x" select=". + 1000"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, to add a condition to the match, use square brackets, like so...

```
<xsl:template match="position/@x[. &lt; 1000]">
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Do you have any solution for my **EDIT**?

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirement here, to be honest. You might need to give an example. Thanks

Comment: I mean something like: `@x < 1000` So the value of the attribute `x` has to be less than 1000 that it will be affected by the calculation.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can simply add conditions to the template match using square brackets `<xsl:template match="position/@x[. &lt; 1000]">`